# How to Join 2 tables ides

Tags: mysql, database, join

How can I join two tables ID. Basically i have two tables number one `user` and second one is `details`.I want when new id generate i mean when new record put in user than this id automatically set in  `details` id.

```
User    ||  Details 
-----------------
id      ||  id
user_n  ||  date_b
pass    ||  sex
        ||  status
```

Comment: Why is this not just a single table?  It doesn't seem like you have a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship here that would require this data to be split into two tables.  That being said, you could investigate use of triggers if you insist on having this data in two tables.

Comment: In actual database so many fields.I was just show some fields for example.thanks for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to create a trigger to insert a new row in Details when a new row is added to User.  It should look something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_NAME` AFTER INSERT ON `User` 
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

INSERT INTO `Details` (`ID`)
VALUES(NEW.ID);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for response can you give me some demo or example code.some thing in written foam.?